# Importing an arbitrarily created Master Private key to Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key, import, xpub

I've created a Master Private key (xpriv) on an airgapped machine along with an Master Public key (xpub). Now I'm running Bitcoind on my Ubuntu server and I want to use my newly created keys on a new wallet rather than the one that Bitcoind created for me when I started running bitcoind.

Is this possible to do? If so what is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to import a master private key into Bitcoin Core.